# Conditionally apply padding to Fragment when switching Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

My Activity first displays a WebView Fragment which must have 0 padding so that the WebView touches the edges of the screen. It then transitions to a ScrollView Fragment which must have 12dp padding inside the ScrollView (and not the Activity) so that the scroll bars are at the edge but the content is padded. However if the ScrollView Fragment is part of a two-pane Activity layout, only the left side must be padded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by sending the padding as arguments from the Activity. If present, the arguments override the Fragment's default padding.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    if (this.getArguments() != null) {
        view.setPadding(this.getArguments()
                .getInt(ARG_PADDING_LEFT, view.getPaddingLeft()), view.getPaddingTop(), this.getArguments()
                .getInt(ARG_PADDING_RIGHT, view.getPaddingRight()), view.getPaddingBottom());
    }

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try this:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if(getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //modify the padding
    }

}
```

**edit:**

Let's say we have a first fragment showing a list of items, and second fragment showing the details, with this code, you will be reusing the DetailsFragment instance if exists.

```
public boolean multiPane() {
    return getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    if(multiPane()) {
        DetailsFragment details = (DetailsFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DETAILS_FRAGMENT");
        if (details != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(details).commit();
            getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.multi_details, details, "DETAILS_FRAGMENT").commit();
        } else {
            //create and show a default details fragment(e.g. the first itme on the list idk)
        }
    } else {
        MyListFragment lf = new MyListFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.list_and_details, lf, "LIST_FRAGMENT").commit();
    }

}
```

This part of the code is used to avoid an exception when changing the DetailsFragment from one FrameLayout container(portrait xml) to another(landscape xml).

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(details).commit();
getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

The exception is:

```
...java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment DetailsFragment...
```

It's a pretty basic example

Comment: The Fragment cannot be aware of its container.

Comment: How will the padding change when I rotate the screen and the Activity switches to a two-pane layout? We won't instantiate the same Fragment twice right?

Comment: Then, you can try creating a landscape xml layout or overriding onConfigurationChanged()

Comment: If I create a landscape XML layout, would I reuse the same Fragment or create a new instance?

Comment: that depends on how you handle the multi-pane inside your activity. If do it the right way you will be reusing the same fragment instance, but inflating the xml padding version of your layout in landscape, I'll add an example to my response.

Comment: But where is the padding of the Fragment being changed? The Fragment cannot change its own padding since it shouldn't be aware of the Activity. It should be padded on both sides for single-pane and only on the left for two-pane.

Comment: The padding would be applied in the landscape version of the Fragment's xml layout

Comment: The Fragment cannot be aware of the Activity. It's also irrelevant whether it's landscape or portrait. If the Fragment is in a single-pane layout both sides must be padded, if it's in a two-pane layout, only the left or right side must be padded. The fragment itself has only one layout.

Comment: I don't get what you mean with that. How is the fragment aware of its activity with the third solution? It only loads its layout from `/layout-port` when it is in portrait or from `/layout-land` when it is in landscape. And, it seems that in the end you used the second solution I posted.

Comment: The Fragment's padding isn't based on its orientation but only on the Activity's layout. There cannot be any deciding logic within the Fragment. You had edited the solution I used out of your answer by the time I came back to the site.

Comment: No man, I think you may be confused about how the layouts are chosen. Android makes that decision automatically. When the framework detects it is in landscape, it searches for the layout in `/layout-land` folder, if there is nothing there, searches in `/layout`, the same with portrait. You don't need to put conditional statements in your fragment to do that, it is the default behaviour of the framework.

Comment: I know. My fragment doesn't have landscape or portrait layouts. It has only one layout. The parent Activity can be single-pane or two-pane. It can be two-pane even in portrait. Even in this case the Fragment must be padded only on one side. The padding is determined by the parent Activity's layout, not based on landscape or portrait.

Comment: ohh also in portrait, ok then